# What is the difference between these two sentences

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-usage

What is the difference between the sentence "He was tired because he was exercising too hard" and "He was tired because he had been exercising too hard"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one implies he was still exercising at the time he was tired. The second implies he was tired *after* exercising. It's a subtle difference but it's there.

Grammatically it's the difference between past tense vs past participle, but you probably don't need to know that.